# Change the Annotation argument using spring AOP

Tags: spring, hibernate, aop, spring-aop

Is there any way to change the annotation parameter using Spring AOP? I have some hibernate annotation with static value and i have to change this value in runtime, Since there is no other way, i am trying to use AOP to change the annotation parameter. Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you want to change an annotation value? BTW, annotation values are constants, not variables. Maybe you are suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) here. Please describe what you want to achieve, not the solution you believe is the way to go. Please also note that on SO we prefer questions including an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kriegaex There is a hibernate annotation called ColumnTransformer, that accept two parameters called read and write. The write parameter is to be filled by JDBC prepared statement binding value. In write parameter, i have to place the PostgreSQL encryption function with symmetric-key and value to be encrypted. But hibernate doesn't provide any way to pass symmetric-key as variable. So i have to hard code this symmetric-key value. i want to avoid this. How can achieve this?

Comment: What about "MCVE" and "XY problem" was unclear? Please be so kind as to edit your question, transforming it into an MCVE instead of just posting a comment with more unclear prose. Let the code speak for itself and make the problem reproducible. Thank you.